# Spring Data Rest parametrized Projection

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-el, spring-hateoas

Is there a way to have a parameterized SpEL expression inside a Projection in Spring Data Rest?

Let's consider an example from Spring Data Rest docs ([link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.4.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.query-method-resource)). We have  Person entity:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  ...
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  ...
}
```

And then we have a projection:

```
@Projection(name = "virtual", types = { Person.class })
public interface VirtualProjection {

  @Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName}") 
  String getFullName();

}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to have a parameter passed to that SpEL expression, something like this:

```
@Projection(name = "virtual", types = { Person.class })
public interface VirtualProjection {

  @Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName} ${id}") 
  String getFullName();

}
```

Where **${id}** is actually and id used to retrieve this Person object from the DB.

Answer (score 2):

Change your projection like this:

```
@Value("#{target.firstName} #{target.lastName} #{target.id}") 
String getFullName();
```

Also go to SpringDataRestConfig and add this:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurer repositoryRestConfigurer() {

    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
            config.exposeIdsFor(
                 Person.class
            )
            .getProjectionConfiguration()
                .addProjection(VirtualProjection.class);
```

I believe it should helps.